# How to force document.execCommand to apply to specific element?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, execcommand

I've been working on a WYSIWYG project that utilizes the `document.execCommand()` method. Currently our toolbar contains a `data-target` attribute, but it's not being utilized to link the toolbar to it's respective editor. A while back we received a couple of reports from users asking for help with this because they were adding multiple editors on the page. Because the `data-target` isn't being utilized in our code, when they use the toolbar on for one editor the styling is being applied on both editors.

I've been looking online for resources to figure this out but every example I've been able to find just shows one editor on the page at a time. Any suggestions as to how I might be able to apply the styling created by the `document.execCommand` to only that editor specified in the `data-target` attribute?

Comment: If `document.execCommend()` applies to the current selection, how is it possible that it affects multiple editors?

Comment: From what I've been able to understand it mostly happens if you leave one editor and start working in another one it affects both editors. So technically you have some type of selection in each editor. Therefore, it's being applied to both.

Comment: So simply remove all selections except this in current editor.

Answer (score 0):

Get the tool bar parent DOM id which you click in one editor.
Get the selected text DOM parent Id.
Compare if both are same means allow to apply the action other wise reject it.